# QT5: How do you Drag and Drop with QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Ok, I've been able to get get Drag and Drop working on `QGraphicsScene`, but not `QGraphicsView`.  My code looks something like this:

```
class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
public:
    GraphicsView(QGraphicsScene *scene) : QGraphicsView(scene) {}

protected:
    void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
    {
            event->setAccepted(true);
            update();
    }

    void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
    {
            event->setAccepted(true);
            update();
    }

    void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
    {
            //stuff that never runs...
            update();
    }
};
```

Although, this code works perfectly fine with `QGraphicsScene` inherited instead of `QGraphicsView`.  I also ran the `setAcceptDrops(true)` function.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In `QGraphicsView` drag & drop events are different from `QGraphicsScene`. See [`QGraphicsView`'s protected functions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QGraphicsView.html#protected-functions) and compare them to [`QGraphicsScene`'s protected functions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QGraphicsScene.html#protected-functions).

Comment: opps, figure it out, the functions to overload are:  void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event), void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event), and void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) not void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event), void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event), void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)